# how to generate pdf from yii2fullcalendar?

Tags: php, yii2, fullcalendar, mpdf

Im trying to generate a pdf file from month and day views of philipfrenzel-yii2fullcalendar with kartik-mpdf and I get this error

**Invalid data received for parameter "events".**

To do it, I've generated an actionIndexPdf($events) method in the controller and a index_pdf.php view file with the yii2fullcalendar widget receiving $events as parameter.

The problem is in the renderPartial of the action. It seems it has a problem with the array of events.

The code is as follows:

Controller CalendarioController.php

```
public function actionIndex() {
        $calendario = Calendario::find()->all();
        $events = [];

        foreach ($calendario as $cal) {
            $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
            $event->id = $cal->id;
            $event->title = $cal->pedido->cliente->nombre;
            $event->id_pedido = $cal->pedido->id;
            $event->sector = $cal->pedido->cliente->sector;
            $event->direccion = $cal->pedido->cliente->direccion;
            $event->telefono = $cal->pedido->cliente->telefono;
            $event->textColor = '#302B16';
            switch ($cal->pedido->estado) {
                case 0:
                    $event->estado = 'Pendiente de entrega';
                    break;
                case 1:
                    $event->estado = 'Entregado sin deuda';
                    break;
                case 2:
                    $event->estado = 'Entregado con deuda';
                    break;
            }
            $event->start = $cal->pedido->fecha_solicitud;
            $event->end = $cal->pedido->fecha_entrega;
            $event->color = $cal->pedido->color;
            $event->allDay = false;
            $events[] = $event;
        }
        return $this->render('index', [
                    'events' => $events
        ]);
    }

public function actionIndexPdf($events) {
        die(var_dump($events));
        Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
        $formatter = \Yii::$app->formatter;
        $pdf = new Pdf([
            'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, // leaner size using standard fonts
            'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_LETTER,
            'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
            'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
            //Se renderiza la vista "pdf" (que abrirá la nueva ventana)
            'content' => $this->renderPartial('index_pdf', ['events' => $events]),
            'options' => [
            // any mpdf options you wish to set
            ],
            'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
            'cssInline' => 'body{
                font-size:12px;
              }',
        ]);
        return $pdf->render();
    }
```

View index_pdf.php

```
<?php

/* @var $this yii\web\View */
/* @var $searchModel app\models\CalendarioSearch */
/* @var $dataProvider yii\data\ActiveDataProvider */

$this->title = 'Calendario de Pedidos';
$this->params['breadcrumbs'][] = $this->title;

?>
<p>
        <?= yii2fullcalendar\yii2fullcalendar::widget([
            'events' => $events,
            'id' => 'calendar',
            'options' => [
                      'lang' => 'es',
                    ],
            'clientOptions' => [
                    'selectable' => false,
                    'editable' => true,
                    'droppable' => true,
                    'header' => [
                        'left' => 'prev,next,today',
                        'center' => 'title',
                        'right' => 'month,listDay',
                        ],
                'height' => 'auto',
                'displayEventTime' => false, 
                    ],
            ]);
        ?>
    </p>
```

button in index.php view

```
    <p>
        <?php 
            //Imprime el boton generar pdf
//        die(var_dump($events));
            echo Html::a('Generar PDF', ['index-pdf', 'events' => $events], 
                        [
                    'class' => 'btn btn-success', 
                    'target'=>'_blank', 
                    'data-toggle'=>'tooltip', 
//    'title'=>'Will open the generated PDF file in a new window'
                ]);
        ?>
    </p>
```

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to pass an array of data as a `GET` parameter on this line:

```php
echo Html::a('Generar PDF', ['index-pdf', 'events' => $events],
```

I imagine that passing the events array is not a requirement for you, in that case, it would be much easier to have both methods generate the array.

Since you are using the same code to get the events on both methods, `index` and `index_pdf`, you could extract that code and call it in both methods to get the `$events`.

You could move the code out of the controller, into a helper class for example, but, for simplicity, I will just add an example using a method inside the same controller.

```php
private function getCalendarEvents() {
    $events = [];
    foreach (Calendario::find()->each() as $cal) {
        $event = new \yii2fullcalendar\models\Event();
        $event->id = $cal->id;
        $event->title = $cal->pedido->cliente->nombre;
        $event->id_pedido = $cal->pedido->id;
        $event->sector = $cal->pedido->cliente->sector;
        $event->direccion = $cal->pedido->cliente->direccion;
        $event->telefono = $cal->pedido->cliente->telefono;
        $event->textColor = '#302B16';
        switch ($cal->pedido->estado) {
            case 0:
                $event->estado = 'Pendiente de entrega';
                break;
            case 1:
                $event->estado = 'Entregado sin deuda';
                break;
            case 2:
                $event->estado = 'Entregado con deuda';
                break;
        }
        $event->start = $cal->pedido->fecha_solicitud;
        $event->end = $cal->pedido->fecha_entrega;
        $event->color = $cal->pedido->color;
        $event->allDay = false;
        $events[] = $event;
    }
    return $events;
}
```

Then call it on both actions

```php
public function actionIndex() {
    return $this->render('index', [
        'events' => $this->getCalendarEvents()
    ]);
}

public function actionIndexPdf() {
    $events = $this->getCalendarEvents();
    Yii::$app->response->format = \yii\web\Response::FORMAT_RAW;
    $formatter = \Yii::$app->formatter;
    $pdf = new Pdf([
        'mode' => Pdf::MODE_CORE, // leaner size using standard fonts
        'format' => Pdf::FORMAT_LETTER,
        'orientation' => Pdf::ORIENT_PORTRAIT,
        'destination' => Pdf::DEST_BROWSER,
        //Se renderiza la vista "pdf" (que abrirá la nueva ventana)
        'content' => $this->renderPartial('index_pdf', ['events' => $events]),
        'options' => [
        // any mpdf options you wish to set
        ],
        'cssFile' => '@vendor/kartik-v/yii2-mpdf/src/assets/kv-mpdf-bootstrap.min.css',
        'cssInline' => 'body{
             font-size:12px;
        }',
    ]);
    return $pdf->render();
}
```

If passing the event array as a parameter **is** a requirement, you will probably need to serialize it to generate the link, and then deserialize it on the `index_pdf` action.

Comment: thanks bro, now it renders but it doesn't show the events. Just a blank page. What can I do?

Comment: Looking at the documentation, it says that all non-standard properties go in an array `$Event->nonstandard = [...]` but you are trying to define them as properties of `$event`

Comment: I've modifiend model Event to add them to it